# Unexpected SyntaxError calling JsonConvert.DeserializeObject()

Tags: c#, json, frameworks

The Chrome console displays the message, "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier" on the line containing JsonConvert in the following fragment. The message is displayed when the page loads. The code is from a *.cshtml file in an MVC.NET project.

```
string json = "{ \"message\": \"hello world!\" }";
dynamic dynJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(data);
```

I used the Manage NuGet command in VisualStudio 2015 to add Newtonsoft.Json. VisualStudio shows that version 10.0.3 of Newtonsoft.Json is installed. I have `using Newtonsoft.Json;` at the top of my *.cs file.

I am unsure if the error is because I haven't included the framework correctly or I am referencing it incorrectly.

Comment: It's been a long time since I used VS but ... did you try to add the library manually on the References which is located in the Solution Explorer?

Comment: The code you posted won't compile, your string is not escaped. Also, you talk about the Chrome console, but showing C# code. I truly do not understand your question.

Comment: Federico, I added the missing escaping of the quotes.